# $this в php - объясните, пожалуйста, по-простому - что это и какой функционал несет в себе

Tags: php

$this в php - объясните, пожалуйста, по-простому - что это и какой функционал несет в себе

Comment: А чем не устраивает это http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this` используется при ООП. Это псевдо-переменная, которая является ссылкой на вызываемый объект,  доступна если свойство или метод был вызван в контексте объекта. Обычно это тот объект, которому принадлежит вызванный метод, но может быть и другой объект, если метод был вызван статически из контекста другого объекта (хотя в PHP7 вызов нестатического метода статическим способом из неподходящего контекста приведет к тому, что `$this` будет неопределен внутри метода).

Пример использования `$this` в классе:

```
class A {
    private $a = 1;

    public function getA(){
        return $this->a; // обращаемся к внутреннему свойсву через $this
    }

    public function someMethod(){
        return $this->getA(); // обращаемся к внутреннему методу через $this
    }
}

$obj = new A();
echo $obj->someMethod();
```

Как видим, писать `$this` можно только внутри области, ограниченной `class {}`

Более подробные примеры можно посмотреть в документации http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php